# Is there any limitation to create "Team Site" subsite in trial versions

Tags: team-sites, limitations

We have installed a trial version of SP 2013 in our organization to check and practice because we have a plan to have SP in future.

But I as and administrator just could give permission to one user to create "Team Site" subsite. Each time only one user could create "Team Site" subsite.

Why is it so?

Comment: is it a  trial Enterprise version?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about "Site Collection Admin" field, which allows you to setup only 1 person through the "create site collection" page. However, you can give user permissions inside that Site Collection... The "Full Control" level, allows users to create subsites, no matter which kind (template).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have  created  5 users and 5 sub sites for them. But only one of them could create sub site beneath it.